# Recode variable in Excel based on other variables

Tags: excel, if-statement, recode

Is there a way to recode a variable using the conditions met by 2 other variables in Excel? Here I have a random table of years and months. I would like to create a new column called "Water year" that starts 4 months after the calendar year starts and has a name of the year it ends in (as of now [5/17/2022] we are in the start of the 2023 "Water year", which starts in May and ends in April 2023). I would like to recode my new column in this way.

So, if a calendar year ("YEAR" column) is associated with a MONTH between May to December (5-12), I'd like the recoded column "Water year" to be that year + 1. If a year is associated with a month between January to April (1:4) the Water year is the same as the calendar year (YEAR). Is there an "IF" statement that can be built to do this?

[image]

Comment: `if(b2<=4,a2,a2+1`)?

Comment: You can also do it with a calculation, `=Round(A2 + (B2+1)/12, 0)`